# Dispatching an action in the function outside mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to know about `dispatch` function and `mapDispatchToProps` function.How they work and when to use.Any guideline for them?

I am currently working on a MERN stack project where i need to post a name on mongoose.I successfully post on database but after posting i also want to send it to redux store via dispatching an action with data.But I am getting `dispatch is not a function error`.Why I an geting this error.I have stated `const {dispatch} = props` in constructor function

Here is my about.js page code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {addName} from '../Actions/actionCreators'

class about extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ req }){
        try{
            const protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http'
            const baseUrl = req ? `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}` : ''
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/users`
            return { apiUrl: url }
        }catch{
            return { error: 'Could not load configs'}
        }
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        const {dispatch} = props
        this.state = { name: '' }
        this.addname = this.addname.bind(this)
    }
    addname(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const {dispatch} = this.props
        const name = e.target.name.value
        const newName = {
            name : name
        }
        fetch(this.props.apiUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(newName),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then( r => 
            r.json()
         )
        .then( (data) => dispatch(addName(data.name)) )
        .catch(err => console.error('POST error', err));
    }
    render() {
        const markup = this.props.name.name.length > 0 ? this.props.name.name.map((elem, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        {this.props.name.name[i]}
                    </div>
                )) : <p></p>
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> About me </h2>
                {markup}
                <form action="" onSubmit={this.addname}>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        submitform : (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        name : state.name
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(about)
```

You can notice `<form action="" onSubmit={this.addname}>` here `addName` is a function which posts the name to databse.

You can also `submitform` in

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return{
    submitform : (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))
    }
  }
}
```

this `submitform` submits directly to redux-state.but i want to submit first to DB and then redux-state

Comment: I would use Promise based library (most probably Axios) to call API endpoint which updates DB and then that API will return latest data. You can use that to update redux store.

`Axios.get('/endpoint').then(response => { dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_ACTION_TYPE", payload: response.data }); return response; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `mapDispatchToProps` you won't have dispatch available as prop to the component. The idea way would be to expose addName from mapDispatchToProps

```
class about extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ req }){
        try{
            const protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http'
            const baseUrl = req ? `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}` : ''
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/users`
            return { apiUrl: url }
        }catch{
            return { error: 'Could not load configs'}
        }
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        const {dispatch} = props
        this.state = { name: '' }
        this.addname = this.addname.bind(this)
    }
    addname(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const {addName} = this.props
        const name = e.target.name.value
        const newName = {
            name : name
        }
        fetch(this.props.apiUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(newName),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then( r => 
            r.json()
         )
        .then( (data) => addName(data.name) )
        .catch(err => console.error('POST error', err));
    }
    render() {
        const markup = this.props.name.name.length > 0 ? this.props.name.name.map((elem, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        {this.props.name.name[i]}
                    </div>
                )) : <p></p>
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> About me </h2>
                {markup}
                <form action="" onSubmit={this.addname}>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        submitform : (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))
        },
        addName: (name) => {
            dispatch(addName(name))
        }
    }
}
```